# ggplot_2 geom_smooth dropped aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

Suppose the data are as follows: 2 continuous variables (`variable_1` and `variable_2`), a `group` factor with 4 levels and a `treatment` factor with 2 levels.

```
df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), class = "factor", levels = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", 
"Group 4")), treatment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), levels = c("Treatment A", "Treatment B"), class = "factor"), 
    variable_1 = c(12.8645664574823, 8.16686874306239, 11.4388230805636, 
    10.3558284665561, 7.69223760253185, 11.6723097558928, 11.6388865156122, 
    12.120960086868, 10.8183228744452, 9.1265042092642, 8.27703056872646, 
    7.31717661690565, 8.96649597992123, 9.38671782428591, 10.8796944597753, 
    12.01665144743, 9.36150447965813, 11.526731214996, 8.22753400261583, 
    8.73540671434093, 12.8645664574823, 8.16686874306239, 11.4388230805636, 
    10.3558284665561, 7.69223760253185, 11.6723097558928, 11.6388865156122, 
    12.120960086868, 10.8183228744452, 9.1265042092642, 8.27703056872646, 
    7.31717661690565, 8.96649597992123, 9.38671782428591, 10.8796944597753, 
    12.01665144743, 9.36150447965813, 11.526731214996, 8.22753400261583, 
    8.73540671434093), variable_2 = c(5.05892658390965, 5.05162026955658, 
    6.66406962970376, 5.00276432258104, 4.10367453808581, 7.45682970015026, 
    7.71323058452055, 4.49113941584846, 3.74111194890247, 3.35332563644038, 
    5.20413950314659, 5.57314098291887, 4.69174992877218, 5.20483325428839, 
    5.71013096825912, 4.97822467530198, 3.07788892862307, 7.03413602373209, 
    5.84712142228627, 5.76742125148379, 5.05892658390965, 5.05162026955658, 
    6.66406962970376, 5.00276432258104, 4.10367453808581, 7.45682970015026, 
    7.71323058452055, 4.49113941584846, 3.74111194890247, 3.35332563644038, 
    5.20413950314659, 5.57314098291887, 4.69174992877218, 5.20483325428839, 
    5.71013096825912, 4.97822467530198, 3.07788892862307, 7.03413602373209, 
    5.84712142228627, 5.76742125148379)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

I want to get a scatterplot with `lm` lines calculated for each `group` level in a colour that corresponds to the `treatment` levels. That is, I want to get 4 lines of 2 colours.

I use the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable_1, y = variable_2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = treatment)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = group, color = treatment), method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

I get a warning:

> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'.
>
> The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical
> transformation: colour
>
> ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping
> structure in the data.
>
> ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a
> numerical variable into a factor?

[image: Example plot output]
The lines in the graph are the same colour (i.e. no colour aesthetic is specified for the lines).

Question: how can I get the desired graph with separate lines for the `group`s but with the colour set by `treatmet`?

It's important that the message about dropped aesthetics appeared recently because on previous versions of ggplot2 (I'm not sure which ones, I'm just using code from an old project) this message didn't appear and the graph was the same as I wanted, with 4 lines and 2 colours. I currently have ggplot2 4.3.0 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want eight lines in total, since there are two treatments in each of 4 groups. In which case, you can map the `group` aesthetic to the interaction of `group` and `treatment`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable_1, y = variable_2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = treatment)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = interaction(group, treatment),
                  color = treatment), method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

This can be made a bit more obvious by labelling the group of each line:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable_1, y = variable_2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = treatment)) +
  geom_textsmooth(aes(group = interaction(group, treatment),
                  color = treatment, label = group), method = "lm", se = FALSE,
                  vjust = -0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Even though I prepared the example incorrectly (in the original I have groups nested within treatments, meaning the intersection still gives 4 lines), your answer worked. Thank you very much.